# Easiest way to access .NET TimezoneInfo from Asp classic page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, com

I need to populate a dropdown list using TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(), but apparently this .net assembly is not exposed. Is there an easier way other than creating a COM object that wraps this class?

Comment: I don't think so, primarily because writing such a COM object in .NET is already quite simple.

Comment: Pretty much what [was said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592060/dealing-with-timezones-in-vbscript#comment62671567_37592262).

Comment: how about using powershell 'GET-Timezone -ListAvailable' ? Is there any example how to do that in ASP classic?